# how to insert inner map in one line insert method

Tags: c++

Lets assume we have a map as below,

```
map<string, map<string, int>> my_map;
```

i want to use insert method in one single line like below

```
my_map.insert("TEST", make_pair<string,int>("ONE",2));
```

and its not working.

i would like to use inner maps for the syntax showed below

```
cout << my_map["TEST"]["A"] << endl;
```

what is the main problem here? should the second inner map be a pair instead?

Comment: What does *"its not working"* mean? Does it compile? If not, what error do you see? If yes, how do you know it's not working? And *"should the second inner map be a pair instead?"* - that depends entirely on the problem you're trying to solve and that you don't show.

Comment: You could use this one liner to add an entry: `my_map["TEST"]["ONE"] = 2;` Why must you use `insert` ?

Comment: as you explain i can use brackets. But i need to find optional way to do this. its just for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the specification for insert: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert. Particularly, you need to provide a pair representing the key and value (for an `std::map`, value_type is `std::pair<const Key, T>`).

Your example of `my_map.insert("TEST", make_pair<string,int>("ONE",2));` don't work since there isn't any overload `insert` that matches your code.

However, there are a number of ways to insert:

```
using new_t = map<string,int> ;
map<string,new_t> easy_map;

easy_map.insert({"A", new_t{make_pair("A", 2)}});
easy_map.insert(make_pair("B", new_t{make_pair("B", 2)}));
easy_map.insert({"C", new_t{{"C", 3}}});
easy_map.insert({"D", {{"D", 4}}});

for (auto &&i : easy_map)
{
    for (auto &&j : i.second)
    {
        cout << i.first << " " << j.first << " " << j.second << endl;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried new thing as shown below and it works.

```
using new_t = map<string,int> ;
map<string,new_t> easy_map;

easy_map.insert(make_pair("A",map<string,int>()));
easy_map.insert(make_pair("B",map<string,int>()));
easy_map["A"].insert(make_pair("A",2));
easy_map["B"].insert(make_pair("B",2));

for (auto &&i : easy_map)
{
    for (auto &&j : i.second)
    {
        cout << i.first << " " << j.first << " " << j.second << endl;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Didn't you ask for a one-line solution in your question?

Comment: yes but i still couldnt figure it out